# How to work with UI from an C# event handler

Tags: c#, winui-3

I Have WinUI 3 App, and there are 4 elements: `App.xaml(.cs)`, `MainWindow.xaml(.cs)`, `LoadingPage.xaml(.cs)` and `RegularContentPage.xaml(.cs)`.

**My task is**: While the code in `App.xaml.cs` do some workarounds I want to display `LoadingPage` in `MainWindow`. After the job in `App.xaml.cs` is finished, change content of `MainWindow` to `RegularContentPage`.

**How I implemented it now:** After the job in `App.xaml.cs` is finished it fires event

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args);
public event EventHandler OnAppIsReady;

OnAppIsReady?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
```

In `MainWindow` by default I display loading page `this.Content = new LoadingPage();`
And catch the `OnAppIsReady` event fired from App:

```
(Application.Current as App).viewModel.OnAppIsReady += APP_OnAppIsReady;
```

In `APP_OnAppIsReady` callback I change the Content of the Window:

```
private void APP_OnAppIsReady(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    this.Content = new RegularContentPage();
}
```

But it throws Exception:

```
WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.<ThrowExceptionForHR>g__Throw|39_0(Int32 hr)
   at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page._IPageFactory.CreateInstance(Object baseInterface, IntPtr& innerInterface)
   at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page..ctor()
```

I tried to rework it with ViewModel, the same case. Tried to rework it using `Frame.Navigate()` and have another exception:

```
WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.<ThrowExceptionForHR>g__Throw|39_0(Int32 hr)
   at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.INavigateMethods.Navigate(IObjectReference _obj, Type sourcePageType)
   at Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigate(Type sourcePageType)
```

Anything I'm trying to do with UI from `APP_OnAppIsReady` callback cause exception and crash.

I suspect that problem here is that event fires in an another thread rather then UI is.
**So question is:** How to properly catch such event from UI?
**And another question:** is there better way to complete my task (programmatically change window's content)?

Comment: When you get exceptions, you should post the exception full text and stacktrace

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was that this code runs in UI thread

```
private void APP_OnAppIsReady(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    this.Content = new RegularContentPage();
}
```

But event fires in another one

```
OnAppIsReady?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
```

To resolve the issue we need to send the event to the right thread via `DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue` like this:

```
this.m_window.DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() => {
    this.OnAppIsReady?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
});
```

In my case I sent it to MainWindow's DispatcherQueue.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that

```cs
private void APP_OnAppIsReady(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    this.Content = new RegularContentPage();
}
```

is not running on the main thread (UI thread). In this case, you can use the `Page`'s `DispatcherQueue` to update UI.

```cs
private void APP_OnAppIsReady(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    this.DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
    {
        // This is running on the main thread.
        this.Content = new RegularContentPage();
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for your tip. Your guess is almost the same as mine: event really fires in the another thread. However trying to catch it from UI thread using this.DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue brought no result: there is no error or success. Then I had an idea: what if I use DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue to fire event instead of catching it. I sent the event to the MainWindow's thread and it works.